# Is the copy/paste approach professionally viable when working with the Google Maps API?

Tags: api, google, copy-paste-programming

I find that I understand much of the Javascript concepts used in the Google Maps API code, but then again there is quite a bit that is way over my head in syntax.

For example, the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) syntax seems to be of Ajax form, though I don't understand what is happening under the hood (especially with lines like `results[0].geometry.location`). I *am* able to modify the body of `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)` for different purposes though.

	So, being that I am able to take various code from the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and rework it to an extent for my own purposes, all the while not fully understanding what Google Maps is actually doing, does this make me a copy-paste programmer?

	Is this a bad practice, or is this professionally viable? I am, of course, interested in learning as much as I can, but what if time-constraints outweigh the learning process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be concerned.  When using an API there are different modes or reasons in using the API - all of them geared at helping developers complete their task in using the API.  Google provides documentation for just this purpose - to use the tool in the way that you need.

Web APIs can also be a special case of publishers providing the 'boilerplate', letting you focus on the task rather than digging into the API design, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Chad, this is reassuring. So, given the purpose of an API, this is a good argument for its' usage to non-developer co-workers.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, set a breakpoint or call `console.log` and examine the data.  It's better (in my opinion) to take a little while to learn the basics than to change things blindly and hope for the best.  You don't need to have a *full* understanding of how the API works, but the more that you know, the easier it will be to make it work for you.

In the case of `results[0].geometry.location` `results` is an array that contains at least one object which has a field named `geometry` containing an object.  This `geometry` object has a field named `location` which is most likely an object with two fields for `lat`itude and `long`itude.

Comment: Absolutely, I test the code and call alerts or `console.log` it to see what variables are passing around. And thank you for the clear explanation about `results[0].geometry.location`.